# Let A be an Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let $A$ be an invertible matrix such that $(A^{−1} + I)$ is invertible.**

**Show that $(A + I)^{−1} = (A^{−1} + I)^{−1}A^{−1}$**.

My attempt at a proof was to take the product of the right hand side and the left hand side in the hopes of getting **I**.

$$(A+I)^{-1}(A^{-1} + I)^{-1}A^{-1}$$
$$= (A+I)^{-1}\big[A(A^{-1} + I)\big]^{-1}$$
$$=(A+I)^{-1}\big[ AA^{-1} + AI\big]^{-1}$$
$$=(A+I)^{-1}( I + A)^{-1}$$
$$=(A+I)^{-1}(A+I)^{-1} $$

Now I'm stuck because I don't know if $(A+I)^{-1}$ is invertible therefore I cannot apply the rule that says if A and B are invertible then $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should take the product with $A+I$.

Comment: @kevin001: That is, you got off on the wrong foot in the first line. To show $B$ is the inverse of $A+I$, you should try to simplify $(A+I)B$ to the identity matrix.  You almost have it.